# It is possible to execute a Python script that is on a Raspberry Pi using Web2Py which is installed on an other machine?

Tags: python, web

I have a Raspberry Pi, that must run a Python script so it can manually turn ON/OFF a LED. Because I don't want to run a web server on the Pi, I installed Web2Py on another machine. For now I can only retrieve data from a MySQL database (temperature and humidity), but I cannot run other scripts using a button from the web page.

Example: I press ON button on the Web2Py server installed on the laptop => Raspberry's Pi LED turns ON. (which is connected to GPIO).

It is possible to do this, or I am wasting my time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your machine with the web server, use paramiko (python library) to communicate with the pi and launch a script there, then get the answer back and display it (if there is one).

On the web server machine :

```
// server.py

def leds_set(state):
  import paramiko
  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  ssh.connect('127.0.0.1', username='ahah', password='lol')
  if state:
    state = 'on'
  else:
    state = 'off'
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python /home/ahah/ledson.py ' + state)
  print(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  return dict()

// view.html
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<form>
<input type="button" onclick="leds_set(True);" value="leds on"/>
<input type="button" onclick="leds_set(False);" value="leds off"/>
</form>
```

On your pi:

```
// ledson.py

state = sys.argv[1]

if state =='on':
  print('Leds ON')
else:
  print('Leds OFF')
```

Comment: Thank you. Do i need to install paramiko on my RPi ? I put your code and my code in Web2Py controllers right ?

Comment: @JohnDow I added a more complete example for you. On your PI you just need to be able to connect via ssh.

Comment: I would never thought to use SSH. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: It does not work properly. I got this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: leds_set is not defined` I think is because it does not know where leds_set is.